# MySQL store string with variable to be filled later

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I'm wondering if it is possible to store variables within a string in a MySQL database and later fill those using (straightforward) PHP. I'll be using this for an action-log of an online management system. I was thinking about implementing it as follows:

Tables:

```
Actions
+------+-----------------------------+-------------------+
| id   | text                        | datatype          |
+------+-----------------------------+-------------------+
| 1    | $a reset the password of $b | [user,user]       |
| 2    | $a added $b to group $c     | [user,user,group] |
| etc  | etc                         | etc               |
+------+-----------------------------+-------------------+
```

and

```
Actions_log
+------+-----------------------------+-------------------+
| id   | action_id                   | variables         |
+------+-----------------------------+-------------------+
| 1    | 1                           | [3281,1008]       |
| 2    | 1                           | [8210,0145]       |
| 3    | 2                           | [3281,1008,12]    |
+------+-----------------------------+-------------------+
```

And then doing some PHP to end up with a string like this:

**3281 reset the password of 1008**

I came up with 2 solutions:

- str_replace("$a",$data);
- Using $data[0], $data[1] and $data[2], etc, as variables and fill the $data array with the data from the table.

I'm not really familiar with PHP yet, the above mentioned solutions don't seem very efficient and even cumbersome. There must be a proper way to do something like this. Anyone has any idea's to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you wanna do that in the first place? Exactly why can't you just store each line of the log in a new record in plain text, no variables?

Comment: I suggest you look into database normalization and relational tables. What you're wanting to attempt here is probably going to bite you back later on, and hard.

Comment: Hi there, I agree... It seems to me much complicated and weird idea. I didn't get it, sorry :-(

Comment: Because the data to be filled into the string is supposed to become a link to the referred object (user, group, etc), otherwise I would be storing it as plain text.